# Cancel Navigation in UWP Prism App

Tags: navigation, uwp, prism

Using the Prism UWP Hamburger example as a basis for an app. The ViewModel implements from Prism.Windows.Navigation.INavigationAware via inheriting Prism.Windows.Mvvm.ViewModelBase. In the main shell is a split view with a tab with buttons such as contacts, about, settings, etc. But if a user selects something like "about" from the split view but the contacts page is displayed and has dirty unsaved data, I would like to ask the user if they wish to discard any unsaved data and then cancel the navigation event if the user does not wish to discard any unsaved data. UWP doesn't seem to have any of the navigation convenience interfaces available in WPF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet tested this myself, but in the samples there seems to be a test case that tries to cancel navigation ( navigating away from a page ) by using NavigatingFromEventArgs and setting property Cancel to true!

```
    public override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingFromEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState, bool suspending)
    {
        e.Cancel = _isNavigationDisabled;

        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e, viewModelState, suspending);
    }
```

Sample code here
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/d2874b5b26baf2590a2b25f780a84f4789c33f4c/Sandbox/Windows10/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.Unity/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs#L44

Comment: Yes already tried this, 2 problems. Firstly can't make this async returning a task as this breaks the OnNavigatingFrom override, but the dialog asking if the user wants to lose unsaved data only has a ShowAsync method. Secondly even if I remove the dialog and cancel the navigation in the content view model the event has already run to completion on in the menu view model which initiated the navigation event.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to handle that, other than .Result the async method ( knowing that is not the optimal way )

Comment: Result works on the details page view model but the navigation menu still ignores this and is out of sync with the details vie model. Brian? Anyone? This has been going for almost 2 weeks. Already asked at Github but was closed and referred back to SO.